# Constraints issues with CollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

All, 
I have a View Controller with a UICollectionView , and the UICollection has a collection of small images (35x35) to make a grid. I am using an inferred size of VC. I  have set the top, bottom, left and right constraints..

The problem is that on the iPhone 6 the amount of cells are correct, but obviously on a iPhone 5 and iPhone 4 there is a smaller amount vertically.

How did I get it so that there is an exact amount of cells vertically on all devices ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with swift, but i hope that this objective-c explanation helps:

In your `-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method you can specify the width and height of your cell.

for example if you only want 2 cells per row and 3 per column user this:

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
     return CGSizeMake(screen.size.width/2 - YourHorizontalPadding, screen.size.height/3- YourVerticalPadding);
}
```

The vertical and horizontal padding is the space you have between your cells, you will have to tweak them to get the desired result.

Hope that helps, let me know if something is not clear.